# rollupPluginBabelHelpers. Bootstrap bug

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, frontend, rollupjs

I'm writing a website on Bootstrap 4. In Internet Explorer, when you try to open the modal for the first time, it works as it should, then does not open it and knocks an error in the console, while the error appears when you try to open the second time on one modal window. If I opened the first window once, then I can not open it, and those who have not yet opened can open, but then they also spawn this error, I use the Gulp collector, I have babel, but I disabled the modules, 
Where does this file, I do not understand, tell me how you can solve this problem.

P.s. In Google found nothing, the only option which I thought will be able to help, it is shutdown of fade at modal, but it did not help in any way. 
Sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPPJi.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A9GS.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOxQj.png]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use an old release of Bootstrap 4, you should update to at least 4.1.1 or 4.1.2